# Block access of a PHP page if visitor doesn't come from a certain page (on same domain)

Tags: php, nginx, http-referer

As title says, I'd like to block visitors from viewing content of a page if they don't come from a specific URL. How can I achieve this? I have PHP over Nginx. Would it be better to use PHP or Nginx?

I read that using `HTTP_REFERER` is not the best idea because it's not mandatory for the browsers... what would you do (code examples)?

Comment: This is pretty much not possible. Relying on HTTP_REFERRER would be the only way to do this, which as you said is no guarantee. It is worse than it not being mandatory though, it could be spoofed!

Comment: The functionality needs to be re-thought. Why do you only want people coming from a specific URL to see it? Could someone not just hand off a link to the page that contains the link to the protected page?

Comment: Here's source code to do exactly that: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~theodore-phpexperts/phpu-training/trunk/view/head:/1.more_secure_sessions/index.php

Comment: If you don't find that existing QA material is fitting, link it anyway and tell specifically what it does not work for you. Do a good research, so that you have linked good site-resources, also it's then more clear what your actual question is. For example you are asking for state with HTTP and the first answer should be cookie, not query-info part (`$_GET`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most bullet-proof solution is to pass a _GET parameter that is not trivial to guess from one page to the next, a-la unique tokens.

It, however, takes a hell of a lot of effort to implement correctly, as it's not the simplest solution, and by far not the simplest to implement either.

In order of complexity, with the simplest at the top, your alternatives are:

- Referer
- Using a fixed GET parameter
- Cookie placed on the user on the first page. Doesn't work for visitors not accepting cookies, and you'll need a cookie policy if you work in the EU.
- Using nonces as GET parameters

**The last solution in detail**

your initial page generates a one-off string, and appends it to every link. You then check if this string is matched with an entry in a database/flat file, and if so, allow access. If not, you deny access. You then invalidate the token so users have to go through the page again.

Comment: _GET is not easily spoofable if the hashing implementation is not trivial. Sessions are also weak if inherently flawed by design.

Comment: (The advantage of _GET is that it makes no assumptions whatsoever on the visitor's set-up. The visitor only needs to be able to click links to go through)

Comment: $_GET is spoofable iff the user knows what to spoof it to.  The idea is to make it secure such that the user cannot know a valid token to spoof unless they visit the gateway page anyway.

Comment: Security through obscurity is not security.

Comment: @zebediah49: exactly my point. If you make the token generation sufficiently complex, and preferably not just based on an algorithm but also a lookup table of valid tokens, it suddenly becomes nearly impossible to spoof.

Comment: This is not security by obscurity, not any more than a flag in a session is. What makes you think that the underlying session cannot be hijacked? That's easy to do on weak implementations, too. The strongest implementation is an unique token stored in a lookup table, as a spoof will have to intercept a token generated on the fly and use it before the actual visitor does. That's only possible in one way: network packet sniffing. It, however, is DB/file-intensive to set up.

Comment: And just to drive my point home - the default session system in PHP checks by session ID alone. There is no IP check, no UA check of any sort. If I can get between you and the server, I can hijack your session. Now if that's not security by obscurity - relying on an underlying module without knowing its flaws...

Comment: it all comes down to what level of security the developer wants.

Comment: Indeed. However, I still maintain that a GET/POST parameter causes less hassle in the end - especially with the new cookie directives if, like me, you have to work in the EU. It's browser-setting agnostic, unlike the default PHP sessions. The rest, as to how secure it is, is up to the user.

Comment: Uhm.. the last solution seems a bit too much. The page that I would like to "hide" if not passing through the other has no state secrets.. :D
No one of the users of the websites would be interested in spoofing it.. :)

Comment: Then just pass a static GET parameter, or if you know that no user would wish to break in, use md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) as token.

Comment: So you mean something like this? :)
In page1.php http://pastebin.com/Whfvsh5D
In page2.php http://pastebin.com/HqBtRP8v

Comment: Kind of. what I mean is page1.php -> page2.php?token=525323464. If the token isn't correct, deny access or redirect to page1.php.

Comment: Keep the session variable the same if you're using sessions. Also, bear in mind that using sessions also has a second drawback - you will be able to tell that your visitor has been on page1 once... but not whether he went directly from page1 to page2.

Comment: Uhm, you're right.. but I don't know how to add the token to the link to page2 and be sure it's checked on page2..

Comment: Again...GET parameters! I'll write you a quick example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iUKxSbqa should provide a very basic example of how it works. Effectively, the token isn't kept in the session, so the only way to acquire it is to modify the links. There is a way to fix the session bit, which is to unset the token on every page of your site. Effort.

Comment: Thanks!! Worked (fixed some typos)!! :D

Answer (score 3):

Probably not perfect, but I would set a $_SESSION on the initial page and then check and remove it on the linked page.

```
$_SESSION['allow'] = 'yes';
```

then on the next page

```
if(isset($_SESSION['allow']) && $_SESSION['allow'] == 'yes') {
    $_SESSION['allow'] = 'now viewing';
}
```

Or something like that....

Comment: this is what I would do.  (appropriately)  assuming that you have control of the referring page.

Comment: This seems the solution to me. I tried to use this, so I created 2 files: page1.php and page2.php.
page1.php: http://pastebin.com/nizNKDzs
page2.php http://pastebin.com/a3U8d2i5

The problem is that I see "Page 2 - landing" both if I visit page2.php coming from page1.php link and visiting it directly (with browser in incognito, so no cookie set).. could be APC the issue? Or I just did something wrong? :)

Comment: you need to add `session_start();` to the top of both those pages.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to restrict access to pages is by using someone's credentials, there's no reliable way to detect where the user came from since that can be spoofed.

Therefore there is no way to allow access to a page B only if the user just came from page A (unless you do it unreliably through `HTTP_REFERER`

You could also set a cookie (or session variable) on page A and not display page B unless the user had the cookie (session variable) set, but that would not require that the user be going straight from page A to page B

Comment: if the user comes from a page you develop, you can pass a session variable.

Comment: @NappingRabbit That's what my comment on cookies mentions (session variables are implemented through cookies)

Comment: A session variable and a cookie are analogous in implementation if you're relying on the default PHP session system, as that's how the sessionID is carried over. Also, one thing many solutions have failed to address is the possibility - which is not said not infirmed by the OP - that the two pages could be on different domains, at which point cookies are not necessarily the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to set a one-time session variable on the first page, and read that variable on the second page.

For example, page 1:

```
$_SESSION['viewed_page1'] = true;
```

Page 2:

```
if(!$_SESSION['viewed_page1']){
  echo 'You need to visit page 1 first!';
}
```

.

Comment: Using a GET/POST parameter is probably a better choice if you're doing one-time session keys, for the cookie issues mentioned in other answers (EU cookie policy, people rejecting cookies, etc.)

Comment: GET/POST can be set by the client. I guess it depends on the amount of validation OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a session variable and pass a particular 'key' from one page, and require it on the following page in order to display it.

you can find info on sessions [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)